# Rails on VIM with no files open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I recently started using (Mac)VIM w/ Rails on VIM plugin.

My workflow is following:
0) open VIM in project's path
1) open new tab in VIM
2) open any file in project
3) do what i need w/ Rails on VIM

Do you have any ideas how to skip 2nd step so that i could run R* commands straight after opening a new tab?

Open some placeholder ({PROEJCT}/readme) on tab open? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a shell script along the lines of

```
cd /project/path
vim README
```

or even just `cd /project/path && vim` - at least on Linux rails.vim detects a Rails app if you start it inside the app's directory

Right now, though, my workflow is exactly the same as yours and I don't mind going through the routine one or two times a day. :)